# R Plotting: Segment behind points -- Not working

Tags: r, plot

I have been on the same problem for a while now and haven't found a solution.
I simply want to make the segments go behind the points instead of going over them.

[image]

The code I am using:

```
for(i in 1:length(x)) {
plot(x[[i]],  rep(length(countries)+1-i,5) , xlim = c(0,200),ylim=c(0,length(countries)),yaxt='n', xaxt='n',ylab='',xlab = '', type='p',panel.first = c(segments(min(x[[i]]),length(countries)+1-i ,  max(x[[i]]) ,length(countries)+1-i)))
  par(new=TRUE)
  }
plot(0, xlim = c(0,200),ylim=c(0,length(countries)),yaxt='n', xaxt='n',ylab='', type='n',xlab=master$Unit[1])
par(las=2)
axis(side=2,cex.axis=.8,at=c(length(countries):1) ,labels=c(countrieslabels))
axis(side=1 ,cex.axis=.8, at=c(seq(0,max(master$DATA_VALUE+5),10))) #currently the ticks are from 0 to 150 seperated by 10
</pre></code>
I have used panel.first with success in the past to achieve something similar so I am confused as to why it is not working here. I thought it might be some little bug when using a for loop in R but then I tried the following:
<pre><code>
plot(x[[1]],  rep(length(countries)+1-1,5) ,panel.first  = c(segments(min(x[[1]]),length(countries)+1-1 ,  max(x[[1]]) ,length(countries)+1-1)), xlim = c(0,200),ylim=c(0,length(countries)),yaxt='n', xaxt='n',ylab='',xlab = '', type='p')
par(new=TRUE)
plot(0, xlim = c(0,200),ylim=c(0,length(countries)),yaxt='n', xaxt='n',ylab='', type='n',xlab=master$Unit[1])
par(las=2)
axis(side=2,cex.axis=.8,at=c(length(countries):1) ,labels=c(countrieslabels))
axis(side=1 ,cex.axis=.8, at=c(seq(0,max(master$DATA_VALUE+5),10))) #currently the ticks are from 0 to 150 seperated by 10
```

So taking one instance of the for loop didn't make a difference so I am stumped now. I also have tried plotting segments first and then the points in a separate plot. Also just changing the type to 'b' is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default point marker is not a filled marker. It's just an unfilled circle. So the order in which the line and markers are plotted shouldn't matter. However, if you use a filled marker, then you just need to plot the line segment first and the point markers second. Compare each of these plots to see what I mean:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

# Filled marker plotted after line
plot(1:10,1:10, type="l", main="Filled marker plotted after line")
points(1:10, 1:10, pch=21, col="black", bg="white")

# Filled marker plotted before line
plot(1:10,1:10, type="p", pch=21, col="black", bg="white",
     main="Filled marker plotted before line")
lines(1:10, 1:10)

# Unfilled marker plotted after line
plot(1:10,1:10, type="l", main="Unfilled marker plotted after line")
points(1:10, 1:10)

# Unfilled marker plotted before line
plot(1:10,1:10, type="p", main="Unfilled marker plotted before line")
lines(1:10, 1:10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I just checked my previous code (where it was working), and checked the differences and found that I had not included pch.